# 404 error - Restful webservice incorrectly considered as perl file

Tags: apache-2.2

I have webapps based on restful webservices running on :
 Apache httpd + mod_jk + Tomcat 6 + Jersey on Centos 6.

The webservice urls r of format :

```
http://<ip-addr>/application/domain/<domain-name>/user/<user-id>?properties=<propertyname>
```

The webservices work correctly under normal circumstances.
However, if the the user id has a value ending with
.pl then I get a 404 error.

Eg.

```
http://192.168.0.17/application/domain/test.dom/user/amol.pl?properties=firstname
```

In httpd error_log, I get error :
    File does not exist: amol.pl

So it seems that httpd is not forwarding the request to tomcat, instead it is looking for the file amol.pl.

I executed the webservice directly on tomcat by doing

```
http://192.168.0.17:8080/application/domain/test.dom/user/amol.pl?properties=firstname.
```

It worked correctly.

I'm not an expert in apache httpd configuration, so I tried some random
tricks to tell httpd to ignore .pl files, with help from google, but could not get it working.

Foll things did not work :

- Remove the "application/x-perl                pl" line from
  /etc/mime.types file.
- Change ExecCGI to -ExecCGI.
- Remove the perl.conf file from /etc/httpd/conf.d
- Add explicit line JkMount /application/*.pl ajp13

But now the problem is I cannot ignore .pl files bcos we do have some .pl files.

httpd.conf is available at `http://pastebin.com/PKwutE1H`.

Virtual host conf file is available at `http://pastebin.com/gNMEyuMh`

Am I correct in understanding that the problem is in httpd configuration ?
Can the problem be solved at httpd level at all ?

Comment: It would help if you could show the httpd configuration, including any rewrites you may have added. (Yes, this can be solved on the httpd level.)

Comment: @JennyD Added links for http conf in question.